# Ubuntu 12.04 locale encoding settings not being honored, seeing ��� a lot

Tags: bash, utf-8, ubuntu-12.04, locale

I'm trying to use a script called bash-git-prompt to make git repositories easier to work with. Part of what this script does is use UTF-8 icons to show the status of your working branch, but the icons are not showing up, and instead I'm getting "���" in their place. It seems to me that there's an encoding problem and the symbols aren't being interpreted correctly.

I ran `locale` and realized that something was wrong because `LANG`, `LANGUAGE`, and `LC_ALL` were blank, and everything else had the value `"POSIX"`. I tried setting these values to `en_US.UTF-8`, which presented its own problems. Changing `/etc/environment` and `/etc/default/locale` did not work, and after a reboot the output of `locale` was the same as before. I ended up adding these lines to my `.bashrc`:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

This successfully updated the locale settings, but I'm still not seeing UTF-8 characters like I should. My output from `locale` right now is:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

But I'm still seeing ��� all the time. Here's an example test:

```
$ echo -e "\xE2\x98\xA0"
���
```

I would expect this command to give me the skull and crossbones symbol ☠, given my locale settings. Is there something else I'm missing here?

Comment: Probably your terminal is not UTF8-compatible.

Comment: I'm using Gnome 3.4.1.1, so it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to change my terminal encoding by going to `menu -> terminal -> set character encoding`, which had an option for `UTF-8`. So I guess now my question becomes, how can I make this the default? When I open a new terminal it defaults back to `Current Locale`, which for whatever reason isn't recognized as `en_US.UTF-8` and instead it gets set to `ANSIX3.4-1968`. How can I make sure `UTF-8` is the default?

Comment: As for this problem, further research has led to the following command to change the default encoding:

`gconftool --set --type=string /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/encoding en_US.UTF-8`